# Text position of a TikZ \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm] at (0, 0) {}
    (0, 0) node[above] {$I$};
    \draw (circle.center) [{Rays[]}-|] -- (circle.east) node[below, midway] {$r$};
    \draw (circle.east)                -- (2, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$};
    \draw (2, 0) [|-{Circle[]}]        -- (3, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$} node[above] {P};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line `(0, 0) node[above] {$I$};` imposes to be integrated in to this line: `\node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm] at (0, 0) {}`. But I couldn't achieve it. How can I make this? Also any other optimization is welcome too.

The desired result (that I want to produce):

[image: desired result]

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrated' exactly? Do you want the `I` to be on the border of the circular node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood correctly, but do you want something like this?

[image: possible desiderata]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm, label=above:$I$] at (0, 0) {};
  \draw (circle.center) [{Rays[]}-|] -- (circle.east) node[below, midway] {$r$};
  \draw (circle.east)                -- (2, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$};
  \draw (2, 0) [|-{Circle[]}]        -- (3, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$} node[above] {P};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Remember that a node is not the same as a path, so you cannot label it in the same way.

In effect, your original code places two nodes at the origin: first the circular one; then the `$I$`. This works because `\node` is equivalent to `\path node`. So you have `\path node ... node ...;` Hence, the second node is placed above the path, which consists of the point `(0,0)`.

## EDIT

Addressing the clarified question, just put the node above the line's starting point. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm] at (0, 0) {};
  \draw (circle.center) [{Rays[]}-|] node [above] {$I$} -- (circle.east) node[below, midway] {$r$};
  \draw (circle.east)                -- (2, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$};
  \draw (2, 0) [|-{Circle[]}]        -- (3, 0) node[below, midway] {$r$} node[above] {P};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: above start]

There are other ways to do this, but this seems as straightforward to me as any.

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank you for an answer. Sorry for the long absence. I added a picture with the desired result to my question.

Comment: @Su-47 Please see edit above.

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank you for the answer! This is really easy solution, but one must have the experience to do it.